# What's the difference between "flet" and "labels" in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

Whether or not it is similar as `setq` and `setf`?  There is no big difference between `flet` and `labels`?

Sincerely!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In Common Lisp, both `flet` and `labels` make lexical bindings of slightly different sorts:

- `flet` is a special form for local function binding. **Bindings are not recursive and cannot refer to each other**. Each binding contains function name, arguments, and function body.
- `labels` is a special form for local function binding. **Bindings can be recursive and can refer to each other**. Each binding contains function name, arguments, and function body.

In Emacs Lisp, there is a small difference.  The *labels* form is like *flet*, except that it makes lexical bindings of the function names rather than dynamic bindings.

Comment: One advantage over flet over labels is that if you define a function `foo` with flet, it can refer to another function named `foo` in the containing scope, whereas with labels it would refer to itself.

Comment: The question was explicitly about Common Lisp, *not* Emacs Lisp. It would be good to remove the first paragraph, as it can cause confusion. There are many Lisp dialects - this question is about Common Lisp.