# Should `flet` be replaced with `cl-flet` or `cl-letf` ?

Tags: emacs

Some elisp functions that I have installed generate warnings:

```
`flet' is an obsolete macro (as of 24.3); use either `cl-flet' or `cl-letf'.
```

Is it dangerous if I simply replace all `flet` with `cl-flet`?
If it is OK to replace them, which one is better?

If it is not dangerous to replace it, I'd send pull requests to the projects.

Is there some reason that they don't change it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`flet` isn't the same as either `cl-flet` or `cl-letf`.
It's more dangerous (and maybe more powerful). That's why it's being deprecated.

Since it's different (binds dynamically a function name), you have to think
in each case if it's appropriate to replace it with `cl-flet`.

#### Small example when `flet` can't be replaced with `cl-flet`

```
(defun adder (a b)
  (+ a b))

(defun add-bunch (&rest lst)
  (reduce #'adder lst))

(add-bunch 1 2 3 4)
;; 10

(flet ((adder (a b) (* a b)))
  (add-bunch 1 2 3 4))
;; 24

(cl-flet ((adder (a b) (* a b)))
  (add-bunch 1 2 3 4))
;; 10
```

Note that `cl-flet` does lexical binding, so the behavior of `adder` isn't changed,
while `flet` does dynamic binding, which makes `add-bunch` temporarily produce a factorial.

Comment: I see. So, it's not easy as I can simply replace all functions. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to decrease your annoyance level, just rip out the definition 
of `flet` from the source, strip the `obsolete` and put it in your .emacs.
It should be the job of package writer to remove `flet` not yours.

Comment: Another option is `(setq byte-compile-warnings '(not obsolete))`

Comment: Byte compile warnings are very useful in my opinion, so I don't disable them.
They're great at capturing variable typos or malformed let bindings.
But there's nothing I can do, as far as I know, about `flet` warning short of rewriting
the package api.

Comment: This post might also help understanding: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9106395/729907

Comment: @abo-abo, my suggestion was only for one specific kind of warning (obsolete), all the rest are still in.  A safe option is to "around defadvice" package-install with a `(let ((byte-compile-warnings '(not obsolete))) ad-do-it)`, if you get your third party libraries via package-install.

Comment: I see, I've misunderstood. But obsolete function warnings good:
when I'm writing some new code and using some function that I've just learned,
it's nice to get a warning "Don't use this function: it will be disabled soon".

Comment: Is there a way to get the old behaviour without using flet then?

Comment: My answer completes your example, showing that `cl-letf` returns 24.

Answer (score 6):

I've recently wrote a [post](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/09/05/a-proper-replacement-for-flet/) on the subject. The gist of the post is that the best replacement for `flet` (if you need dynamic binding) is [noflet](https://github.com/nicferrier/emacs-noflet). It's a third party library, but it's almost a drop-in replacement for `flet` (while adding some extra capabilities).

Comment: No need for a third-party library.  See my answer that shows `cl-letf` in action.

Answer (score 5):

The `cl-letf` function can be used for dynamic binding of functions, as Artur describes in [this](http://endlessparentheses.com/understanding-letf-and-how-it-replaces-flet.html) blog entry.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your function to use `lawlist-flet` or create an alias -- all I did was remove the warning and rename the `flet` macro to `lawlist-flet`:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; FLET ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(defmacro lawlist-flet (bindings &rest body)
      "Make temporary overriding function definitions.
    This is an analogue of a dynamically scoped `let' that operates on the function
    cell of FUNCs rather than their value cell.
    If you want the Common-Lisp style of `flet', you should use `cl-flet'.
    The FORMs are evaluated with the specified function definitions in place,
    then the definitions are undone (the FUNCs go back to their previous
    definitions, or lack thereof).
    \(fn ((FUNC ARGLIST BODY...) ...) FORM...)"
      (declare (indent 1) (debug cl-flet)
    ;;           (obsolete "use either `cl-flet' or `cl-letf'."  "24.3")
                    )
      `(letf ,(mapcar
               (lambda (x)
                 (if (or (and (fboundp (car x))
                              (eq (car-safe (symbol-function (car x))) 'macro))
                         (cdr (assq (car x) macroexpand-all-environment)))
                     (error "Use `labels', not `flet', to rebind macro names"))
                 (let ((func `(cl-function
                               (lambda ,(cadr x)
                                 (cl-block ,(car x) ,@(cddr x))))))
                   (when (cl--compiling-file)
                     ;; Bug#411.  It would be nice to fix this.
                     (and (get (car x) 'byte-compile)
                          (error "Byte-compiling a redefinition of `%s' \
    will not work - use `labels' instead" (symbol-name (car x))))
                     ;; FIXME This affects the rest of the file, when it
                     ;; should be restricted to the flet body.
                     (and (boundp 'byte-compile-function-environment)
                          (push (cons (car x) (eval func))
                                byte-compile-function-environment)))
                   (list `(symbol-function ',(car x)) func)))
               bindings)
         ,@body))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cl-letf`.  Continuing the example given by @abo-abo,

```lisp
(cl-letf (((symbol-function #'adder) (lambda (a b) (* a b))))
  (add-bunch 1 2 3 4))
```

returns 24.