# Lisp Anonymous Function Local Variable

Tags: function, clojure, lisp, common-lisp

How do I assign anonymous functions to local variables in either cl, emacs lisp or clojure?

I've tried the following with no success.

```
(let ((y (lambda (x) (* x x)) )) (y 2))
```

and

```
((lambda (x) 10) (lambda (y) (* y y)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CL, you could use `flet` or `labels`.

```
(defun do-stuff (n)
    (flet ((double (x) (* 2 x)))
      (double n)))

(do-stuff 123) ;; = 246
```

As Chris points out, since `double` is not recursive, we should use `flet`, as the difference between the two is that `labels` can handle recursive functions.

Check out [docs](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm) for info on `labels`, or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105870/whats-the-difference-between-flet-and-labels-in-common-lisp) for the difference between `labels` and `flet`.

Comment: Except, in this situation, you can (and should) use `flet` instead of `labels` because your `double` procedure is not recursive.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Shouldn't that be a compile time(or something) because it is a built in command.  Coming from Mathematica it makes no distinction between the 2

Comment: @William In this case, there's no difference between using `flet` or `labels`. The main difference comes when you're referring to the name that is being defined (`double`, in this case): if you use `flet`, any references to `double` refers to a `double` that was defined before the `flet`; whereas if you use `labels`, any references to `double` refers to the function you're defining here.

Comment: @William To make it easier for people to read your code, it's better to reserve the use of `labels` for cases where a recursive function is really being defined, so that when people see `labels`, they automatically think "recursive function".